# IoT devices data transfer uses SSL/TLS to encrypt or plaintext? If it using grpc?

Tags: iot, http2, grpc

Does anybody knows IoT devices uses grpc to transfer with encrypted data or plaintext? I heard somebody says if there are massive IoT devices it would uses plaintext to transfer data. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

For IoT, always encrypt your data. By default, use TLS.

There are devices using plain text. They do it to save device hardware costs and compromise at security. Typical devices include tracking/GPS devices. Security-aware companies refuse to use these devices.

GRPC is to my knowledge not widely used in the context to IoT remote connections.